# Strategy of deploying code changes on EC2

Tags: amazon-ec2

Let's pretend that I have 10 EC2 instances and RDS (mysql). After some changes I have to deploy them on all instances (eg. change source code, change Mysql schema, restart Nginx). What is preferred method to do that?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If the changes to MySql are not backward compatible, there's no other way but to put up a maintenance page on all of your instances. Do the mySql update, redeployment and restart of your webserver.

However, if the changes to MySql are backward compatible, you should go with a rolling deployment. First upgrade the database. Then, upgrade each instance one at a time. Ensure that the LB is not sending traffic to the nodes while they are being upgraded.